# Printing actionMessages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have the following code:

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <s:actionmessage/>
</s:if>
```

How can I display a message in an alert box using javascript or jQuery, instead that printing them in HTML ?

Comment: What have you tried? If you're using something like Fancybox or jQuery UI dialogs, you could stick the above code in a div, and use that as the Fancybox/Dialog container...

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the Action Messages in Javascript (instead that in HTML) and then showing them in a javascript alert, or in a jQuery modal dialog, or whatever, you can manually iterating, printing and escaping (for javascript injection) them like follows:

```jsp
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <script>
        <s:iterator value="actionMessages">
            alert('<s:property escapeJavascript="true" />');
        </s:iterator>
    </script>
</s:if>
```

or

```jsp
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <script>
        var msgs = "";
        <s:iterator value="actionMessages">
            msgs += '<s:property escapeJavascript="true" />\n';
        </s:iterator>
        alert (msgs);
    </script>
</s:if>
```